# Webpack bundle behaviour different from 5.21.0 and 5.22.0

Tags: javascript, webpack, eval

I am doing some upgrades to node a package which uses webpack. The package used to use webpack 5.9 for generating a small bundle, then using `eval()` was extracting some js code.

This is the webpack conf:

```js
function getBaseWebpackConfig() {
  return {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: "./test/input/icon.js",
    devtool: false,
    output: {
      path: outputDir,
      filename: bundleFileName,
      publicPath: '',
      library: {
        type: 'commonjs2',
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.svg/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: svg-loader,
          options: {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, moving to 5.73.0, this behaviour has changed; tests stopped running. After doing some debug, I have found the following.

With **webpack < 5.21.2** the bundle starts as:

```
module.exports =
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({
```

With **webpack > 5.22.0** the bundle starts as:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({
```

Essentially, it does not have a top `module.exports` anymore and this breaks the rest of the code.

I could not find any reason this. The changelog does not give me any clue. Might it be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a webpack expert.  But, comparing yours with my webpack configs I created recently (using the latest webpack for a PWA app).  My settings are inside a module.exports.  Maybe that's why module.exports is not in your bundle. e.g.

```
 module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: "./test/input/icon.js",
    devtool: false,
    output: {
      path: outputDir,
      filename: bundleFileName,
      publicPath: '',
      library: {
        type: 'commonjs2',
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.svg/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: svg-loader,
          options: {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Plus I've got three webpack config files common,dev and prod and use merge to combine them.
e.g. my webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerNotifierWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-notifier-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',  
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    },
    module: {        
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css"
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerNotifierWebpackPlugin(),
    ]
});
```

Comment: Interesting. My webpack is started by jest for testing a loader. I can definitely export the config with module export and reimport to run it, but feels nosense. The change log between 5.21.2 and 5.22 does not list anything can be related to this.